# Searching in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have tree tables - `table1`, `table2` and `table3`. Their structure is something like this:

```
table1 = id | data
          1 | x
          2 | y

table2 = id | table1_id | table3_id | data
          1 | 1         | 1         | a
          2 | 2         | 2         | b
          3 | 1         | 3         | c
          4 | 2         | 3         | d

table3 = id | data
          1 | e
          2 | f
          3 | g
```

And now I want to search by `table3.data` (using LIKE) and get related table1 data. How should the SQL look like?

For example:

In my web application i type "g" - so i will look at the `table3` a return ID = 3, in `table2` there are 2 rows with `table3_id` = 3 and result i want to get is collection of all rows with `table1.id = table2.table1_id` so

```
id | table3.data
 1 | g
 2 | g
```

Comment: Edit your question with examples of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Why do you want to use LIKE?

Comment: Sory for the LIKE - it's probably confusing - the 'data' column contains a string and I want to search by all substrings.

Comment: This question is very confusing. First you say "and get related table1 data." But in your example output there is no table1 data. Also what you need LIKE for isn't clear at all. If you type 'g' do you want to select all rows from table3 with the letter 'g' in data? Or maybe what you mean is if you type "fg" you want to select rows from table3 with 'f' or 'g' as data value?

Comment: Sory for not being that exact - but i think it isn't that hard to understand what I'm asking about. But just to make sure - I want to search all rows from tabl3 containing 'g' in data column and then I want to select related rows from table1. It's an ordinary searching mechanics in a website... but i've got that weird DB structure. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you defiantly don't need to use `LIKE` , you need to do a simple `JOIN` task, `LIKE` is used for partially string comparison -> `'Full string' LIKE '%Fu%'`.

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id as t1_id,t3.data as t3_data
FROM table3 t3
INNER JOIN table2 t2
 ON(t3.id = t2.table3_id)
INNER JOIN table1 t1
 ON(t2.table1_id = t1.id)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that with SELECT from 'table1' ?

Comment: Try updated query, if I understood you correctly @sukovanej

Comment: This SQL SELECT from table3 and JOINs table2 and table1. I need to do select on table1 and join table2 and table3...?

Comment: @sukovanej It's the exact same thing:) Think about it that way -> `1 + 2 + 3` equals `3 + 2 + 1`

Comment: But wait a minute... there's not the 'g' value. I need to get all the table1 rows by some 'WHERE' statement applied on table3.

Comment: @sukovanej This is what this query does! bring the `ID` from `table1` with the corresponding value from `table3`

Comment: Finaly I found what I want. I was just confused of using JOIN and did't quite realized the difference between writing conditions into JOIN ON and WHERE statement. What you wrote is still not what I wanted (the WHERE statement is missing) but i got the idea.

Comment: Well, this is the proper syntax of a join (as opposed to comma separated joins, and then using the where clause) . Its the same and you should get used to write it in the write way. For clarification - both of the `ON` clause equals to `WHERE t3.id = t2.table3_id AND t2.table1_id = t1.id` @sukovanej